# Converting Hunter: The Vigil to nWoD 2nd Edition

Tags: homebrew, chronicles-of-darkness-2e, hunter-the-vigil

I would like to run Hunter: The Vigil with the God Machine Chronicle rules. Hunter has not yet been updated yet for the new rules, but how hard would it be to convert the rules a bit myself? The PCs in Hunter a pretty much mortal, so I am thinking the rules would follow the core book more closely anyway? Can someone tell me of potential issues I would run into by doing this? Thanks.

Comment: It looks like I can maybe use the "Mortal Remains" rules on http://rpg.stackexchange.com/tags/nwod-god-machine/info to do a conversion?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The book *[Mortal Remains](http://rpg.drivethrustuff.com/product/129193/Hunter-Mortal-Remains)* contains rules for updating Vigil to 2.0 rules, as well as Dread Powers for monster types not covered in the other books.

Use those conversion rules.

The only real issue you would run into if you don't use the *Mortal Remains* rules is how to adjudicate Integrity with Hunters' ability to replace "morality sins" in service of the Hunt.

Comment: mmm... as an adendum mortal remains updates all of the Endowments, though the tweaks are minor, it also updates Practical XP to the Beat system. However the biggest hunter things, such as Profession, was moved into Core in GMC, so...